# Why variable cannot be used for casting datatype in Pyspark

Tags: dictionary, pyspark, casting

I could not get why it behaves this way. I want to dynamically cast dataframe new column. but it throws error. where as if we directly mention, it is working.
your input will help me to rectify my mistake.

`````
input_dict = {"memo":"None","office":"SYD,StringType()","off_no":"987654,IntegerType()"}

valu = input_dict.get(i).split(",")
print(valu[0],"````",valu[1])
cast_to =valu[1]
print(cast_to)

df = df.withColumn(i, lit(val[0]).cast(**cast_to**))
`````

## throws error as

```
df = df.withColumn(i, lit(val[0]).cast(cast_to))
..\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\column.py:774: in cast
    jc = self._jc.cast(dataType)
..lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1321: in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
```

when I give the cast directly. it is working. not sure, why it behave like it. If I assign the datatype to- variable and use it in cast, it is throwing error. I may get any data type in dictionary. so it has to be dynamic.

```
df = df.withColumn(i, lit(val[0]).cast(**StringType()**))
```

#Working

**print:**
SYD ```` StringType()
StringType()

I tried in different way and google it. could not get any inputs. Need your inputs why it is not working with variable dynamic types.

Comment: `"StringType()"` and `StringType()` are not the same thing.

Comment: create a map from "StringType()" to "string" etc and then pass that in. `.cast("string")`  , this will cast it to required datatype.